# Apply blur effect to a view before presenting on IOS 7/8?

Tags: ios, objective-c

im working on an app involving privacy, and i would like to blur the main screen when app starts (then I ask for local authentication etc..)

The main problem i'm having, is that i don't know how to access the view before it is displayed. 
If i try to get the view inside `- (void)viewDidLoad` then blur effect is not applied (since the view doesn't exist yet) and if i try to access the view inside `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` then the non-blurred view appears for a second before the blur effect is applied.

There is a way to get the view and apply the blur effect before it is displayed on screen?

The code im using for applying the blur effect is:

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
UIVisualEffectView * visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
visualEffectView.frame = self.view.window.bounds;
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`?  Furthermore, you should design the view with the blur layer there initially and hide it when you no longer need it.

Comment: Maybe make the content in main view hidden (add it to subview and hide it) in viewWillAppear?

Comment: Try viewWillDisplay perhaps.

Comment: @jeffamaphone - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated Doesn't work, same problem. View is not yet rendered so blur is not applied.

Comment: @Yanchi I know there are other solutions, like hide views or overlay with something, but i like the blur effect and would like to use it.

Comment: @GuillermoMP I'm not saying to ditch blurView :) I'm saying that you should add your content that you want to obscure to UIView and hide this UIVIew in viewdidload

Comment: @GuillermoMP did you try viewDidAppear?

Comment: @MDB983 Yes, but there is a huge delay and the non-blurred version is displayed for ~1sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why but getting & blurring the views in the main thread worked fine, even in the `- (void)viewDidLoad`. Blur is instant and the non-blurred version doesn't show at all.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //blur here
    });
```

Now it works fine, even when called from the AppDelegate!

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // ...
    [self addBlurLayer];
    // ...
    return YES;
}

-(void)addBlurLayer
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(visualEffectView==nil)
        {
            UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
            visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
            visualEffectView.frame = self.window.bounds;
            [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject addSubview:visualEffectView];
        }
    });
}
```